# Proving that error vector to least squares solution is orthogonal to the columns of $A$

Tags: linear-algebra, proof-verification, orthogonality, least-squares

I have to prove that the error vector to least squares solution is orthogonal to the columns of $A$. This means that the error vector $Ax - b$ is in the nullspace of the transpose of $A$. However, I am now stuck.

Here's what I have

\begin{align}
x & = (A^TA)^{-1} A^T\cdot b \\
(A^TA)x & = A^T\cdot b \\
(A^T)^{-1}(A^TA)x & = (A^T)^{-1} A^T\cdot b \\
A\cdot x &= \mathbf{b} \\
\end{align}

Can someone give me a hint?

Answer (score 1):

Consider starting with $A^T(Ax-b)$ and show this equals zero, which is another way of saying the error vector is in the null-space of $A^T$.  In particular, you'll need to substitute the least-squares solution for $x$ in the above, like this:

$A^T(A[(A^TA)^{-1}A^Tb]-b)$

I hope this helps.